# Can I pass a pointer using memory mapped files?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, pointers, ipc

I have read the article about [Memory-Mapped Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx) and the example about [CreateFileMapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx).
My question is: Can I pass a pointer to a struct or a object between two processes using memory-mapped file?

---

Since there are some answers that it is possible, here is struct that I want to pass:

```
// First Process
struct OtherStruct{};

struct MyStruct
{
    unsigned long       handleObject;
    unsigned long       *phandleObject;
    OtherStruct         someData;
    OtherStruct         *pData;
}

MyStruct dataSend = { ... };
WriteToMappedFile(data);

// Second Process
MyStruct dataReceived = ReadFromMappedFile()
```

Comment: You will have to `memcpy` the content of the struct to the memory mapped file.

Comment: To clarify your question: Do you want to know if you can pass a pointer via the memory-mapped file (which you definitely can) or if you will be able to access the struct from the other process (which you only can if the struct lies within the memory-mapped area as well). In this case, because each process has its own virtual memory layout, you will have to use addressing relative to the memory-mapped file. See my answer below for details.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Can you give me some examples?

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more specific what you want to pass from the one process to the other. Are you using data structures that use pointers to reference different nodes (like linked lists, trees, graphs)? Or would it be possible to pass the struct *by value* instead of passing the pointer? This would simplify things a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other answers already stated, you must either rely on the address of the  memory-mapped areas to be equal, or you must move from absolute addresses in your pointers to relative addressing.

One possible implementation I stumbled across recently is the [offset_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/interprocess/offset_ptr.html) in the Boost library, which seems to fit your use case perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on what you want to achieve. Passing a pointer in shared memory is easy, but the other process may not be able to use it in the way you expect.

Note that a pointer contains a virtual address of the data structure it points to. Such a virtual address is only valid within the process that holds the pointed-to data structure. If you pass the pointer to another process, the other process will have its own virtual address space, and the passed pointer loses its validity.

So the answer to your question is: Yes, you can pass the pointer, but without further actions, you won't be able to successfully use this pointer in the receiving process. Specifically, you will most probably not be able to use it for accessing the struct or object it points to.

If you want to access the struct or object within the other process, you need to do the following:

- Put the object itself into shared memory.
- Convert the pointer to the object into an offset relative to the beginning of the memory mapped file.
- Pass this offset to the other process
- In the other process, use the offset to convert back to a pointer.

`boost::offset_ptr` can help you with part of that.

Comment: Can you give me more details about "Convert the pointer to the object into an offset relative to the beginning of the memory mapped file." How can I implement it?

Comment: See the documentation of [boost::offset_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/interprocess/offset_ptr.html) for more information.

Comment: If you want to do it manually, and you are using the mmap() call for mapping a file to memory, you use the return value of mmap() as the base address, which you subtract from the address of the object within the mapped memory region, to form the offset. Note that you will have to cast the pointer type to char*, since you can't subtract void*.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Pointer is to a struct that is part of the same memory mapped region, yes that can make sense. but then you will have to ensure that the memory mapped region is mapped to the same virtual address, this is not always guaranteed and is a bad way to design things.

You can pass the offset instead and deal with relative offsets everywhere fpor structures present in this memory region.

Comment: I would rewrite that saying "**No**, its not possible, _unless_ its mapped to the same memory mapped region (which you usually cannot control)..."

Comment: thanks, but I think No is a very strong word MapViewOfFileEx does take a base address, I have squirmed at code that actually uses that field, but there are scenarios where a custom shimming/hooking scheme that overlays a DLL can get away with it.

Answer (score 0):

<del>If the pointer you want to pass into the memory-mapped-file is not allocated by GlobalAlloc, and not locked by GlobalLock, it can't.</del> However, you have already the memory allocated to pass the data. So you can re-write the memory on the memory-mapped-file.

Comment: Globalalloc simply allocates from global heap of that process it will not point to the structure in another process' address space.

Comment: the "anymore" has been any more since dinosaurs walked earth you can come out of your cave anytime now. :D